# how to display kendo tooltip for kendo grid column menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to display tooltip for the column menu in the kendo UI grid.
I have defined like

```
$(".k-header-column-menu").kendoTooltip({
            content: "column menu"
        });
```

but it is not displaying any tooltip.
can any one help me how to give the tooltip for column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not your code but *when* you run it. If you do it just after initializing the grid, the grid menu still does not exist and then you are not defining the `Tooltip`. Run that code in the `Grid` `dataBound` event.

Example:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data    : createRandomData(300),
        pageSize: 10,
        schema  : {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Id       : { type: 'number' },
                    FirstName: { type: 'string' },
                    LastName : { type: 'string' }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    columnMenu: true,
    columns   : [
        { field: "FirstName", width: 90, title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName", width: 90, title: "Last Name" }
    ],
    dataBound: function () {
        $(".k-header-column-menu").kendoTooltip({
            content: "column menu"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If I define in the dataBound event also,it is not displaying

Comment: hi,If i define column menu in the databound event,It is displaying.I am trying to implement the same for edit and delete buttons.Initially tooltio is displaying,once If I edit any record in the grid,next time onwards tooltip is not displaying .

Comment: This is because you have to re-enable each time. That's why I did it in databound and not just once in initialization. Nevertheless you can achieve the same using a convenient CSS selector. Give me more details on what you try to do or even better modify my JSFiddle for showing it and I will try to help you.

Comment: I have multiple records in my grid.For each record I have edit and delete buttons.For buttons I removed the text and displaying only image.I am trying to display the tooltip for edit and delete images.As of now I defined the tooltip in databound event,Intially it is displaying,after editing any record tool tip is not displaying

Comment: Not sure how did you remove the text but this http://jsfiddle.net/JCSGz/9/ works when there is text. Show me one that fails and I'll take a look

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JCSGz/15/ see this fiddle,I put tooltip for update button but tooltip is not displaying.how to display tooltip fot update and cancel buttons.I put in dataBound but it is not working

Comment: The problem is that in on `dataBound` the element (popup) is still not created so you are setting the tooltip to nothing. This, you need to do it in `edit` event handler. Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/JCSGz/17/

Comment: It is working fine.but as I told earlier tooltip for edit button is displaying initially,After editing any record next time onwards tooltip is not coming for edit button

Comment: My last fiddle works fine to me! Which browser / OS are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome/windows7 browser,your fiddle is working in my system also

Comment: yah,I took cancel function,In this I gave like datasource.cancelChanges(); then it is working fine in my case,Tool tip is coming every time for edit button,Is it causes any performance issue?

Comment: No, it does not! Ok, it has an impact but the impact in performance of creating the editing form each time is much worse. Obviously we can try to optimize the jQuery call to do not have to look for every node in your HTML page just in case it has the class that you want and that's always nice to do.

Comment: The "efficient" version might be something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/JCSGz/18/